# Why does the JVM have a maximum inline depth?

Tags: java, jvm, jit

`java` has an argument `-XX:MaxInlineLevel` (with a default value of 9) which controls the maximum number of nested calls to inline.  Why is there any such limit? Why aren't the usual heuristics based on frequency and code size sufficient for the JVM to decide for itself how deeply to inline?

(this is prompted by [JitWatch](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/jitwatch) showing me that a deeply nested Guava `checkArgument` call was not being inlined due to depth)

Comment: Not at all certain but probably to avoid mutual recursion traps which can be difficult/expensive to defend against in other ways.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon but then you have the MaxRecursiveInlineLevel

Comment: @MrSimpleMind - Interesting - I am therefore clearly wrong. Must be some other reason.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some significant searching uncovers this interesting little [fragment](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/12587414/) (I actually got as far as page **4** of the Google search):

```
    if (inline_depth() > MaxInlineLevel) {
        return "inlining too deep";
    }
    if (method() == callee_method
            && inline_depth() > MaxRecursiveInlineLevel) {
        return "recursively inlining too deep";
    }
```

Which suggest that the `MaxInlineLevel` is as expected a hard limit to how deep you go before you stop inlining. It also suggests that the `MaxRecursiveInlineLevel` refers only to direct recursive calls, not mutal recursive calls such as `foo()` calls `bar()` which calls `foo()`.

So I think I was right in my guess comment - `MaxInlineLevel` is to protect against **mutual** recursion because to detect that you would need to keep references to the full depth of the inlining call stack.

`MaxInlineResursionLevel` controls `foo()` calls `foo()` inlining.

Note that the referenced code may not be a real JVM.

Comments by @apangin locates a more modern version of hotspot from Open JDK 8 suggest that it is nowadays no longer quite as simple as that. It looks like the full stack is searched for recursive calls so mutual recursion may also now be blocked from going past `MaxRecursiveInlineLevel`.

Comment: You look at the very old sources. The right place is at [hg.openjdk.java.net](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/). `MaxRecursiveInlineLevel` counts both [direct and indirect](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/c1374141598c/src/share/vm/opto/bytecodeInfo.cpp#l389) recursive calls.

Comment: @apangin - That does not seem to be doing what the comment says. Also it's only comparing against `MaxRecursiveInlineLevel`. Good find though.

Comment: Dig deeper. [The loop](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/c1374141598c/src/share/vm/opto/bytecodeInfo.cpp#l401) walks through all frames looking if the callee method presents anywhere on the stack. [MaxInlineLevel](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/c1374141598c/src/share/vm/opto/bytecodeInfo.cpp#l380) is now set in InlineTree constructor.

Comment: @apangin, probably you know the correct answer to this question?

Comment: @TagirValeev Not exactly, but I guess the basic reason is to keep things simple. Unlimited inlining depth would increase complexity, the compilation time and memory usage might be less predictable (that is OK for AOT compilers, but not for JIT). Also mind that compiled code should keep track of the whole inlining tree at run-time (to be able to unwind and deoptimize). Though I think the default value of 9 is outdated. It has not been changed for ages, but nowadays, with much more resources available, with streams and lamdas in mind, there is definitely a place for improvement.

Comment: One reason is also that the inlining itself in the HotSpot JVM is implemented with recursion. Every time inlining of a method is started a new context is created on the native stack. Allowing an unlimited depth would eventually make the JIT-compiler crash when it runs out of stack.

Comment: typo: MaqxInlineResursionLevel should be MaxInlineResursionLevel

Comment: @NitsanWakart - Done - next time happy for you to change it - SO encourages that kind of thing.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Only if you edit 10 chars or more sadly... :-)