# Why there is no infrastrucutre for hinting JIT compiler in JVM?

Tags: java, jvm, jit

I was reviewing one conference presentation that touched JIT inlining semantics where author pinned down weird behavior (weird only for first look, of course) - C2 was slower than C1 because it couldn't inline method due to excessive inlining depth. It may be represented in following example:

```
public static int multipleByTwo(int x) {
    return x * 2;
}

public static void entrypoint() {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10_000_000; i++) {
        // due to some arbitrary cause, multiplyByTwo doesn't get inlined
        sum += multiplyByTwo(i);
    }
}
```

As a programmer, i may know there is a field for optimization that compiler doesn't know about. E.g. there is plenty of optimization possible if `multiplyByTwo` would be forcibly inlined, but due to various constraints (e.g. method size or inlining depth) it may be omitted from inlining. Why there is no way to tell the compiler "hey, i'm pretty sure you should prefer inlining that method rather not"? I'm sure i'm not the first one to think about this and there was discussion that resulted in not implementing such feature - why?

p.s. please note that i'm talking about hints rather than directives; i do understand that latter choice would result in more harm than benefit.

Comment: The AI Algorithms to determine when and how to optimize the runtime by JIT, like method inline, is a really really tough to grasp.
But making method 'final' can hint java to make it inline. AFAIK there isn't any way to tell JIT to make method inline for sure.

Comment: Presumably this particular problem would go away if the max inlining depth were greater - and so the question is then [why is there a maximum depth](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32503669/3788176); or, why can't you just increase that depth using the JVM argument. More generally, the question is "why does the JIT stop doing X optimization when Y": because the authors of JIT can't spend an infinite amount of time ensuring that every possible case is handled. It works *pretty well* in the majority of cases.

Comment: @vvtx yes, i know i can't dictate compiler (at least in modern jvm). My question is 'why nobody implemented that?' rather than 'how do i force compiler to inline at my will?'

Comment: @AndyTurner yes, i know about max inlining depth. But developer may hint the compiler that it should inline one method deeper rather than inlining from top one (keeping the specified depth) if he's sure that will benefit overall performance. The whole question is not about inlining itself, it just shows an example where developer intrusion may result in performance benefit, but, due to unknown cause, that intrusion is not possible - and i want to know that cause.

Comment: My comment wasn't about inlining, per se. It's pointing out that there are necessarily practical limitations in what it is worth the JIT trying to optimize, and the fact that it works pretty well in the vast, vast majority of cases obviates the additional complexity of a hinting mechanism.

Comment: @AndyTurner sorry, was distracted and didn't read throughly, my bad

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In fact, **there is** an infrastructure to control HotSpot JVM compiler.

#### 1. Compiler command file

You may specify a file containing compiler commands with `-XX:CompileCommandFile=` JVM option. There are commands to force inlining, to exclude a method from compilation, to set a per-method option (e.g. `MaxNodeLimit`) and so on. The full list of available commands can be found [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/b4bdf3484720/src/share/vm/compiler/compilerOracle.cpp#l317).

An example Compiler command file may look like

```
inline java.util.ArrayList::add
exclude *::<clinit>
print com.example.MyClass::*
```

#### 2. Annotations

JDK-specific annotations are another way to control JVM optimizations. There are certain annotations that HotSpot JVM knows about, e.g.

- [`@java.lang.invoke.ForceInline`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/0e4fc29a5ce4/src/share/classes/java/lang/invoke/ForceInline.java#l30)
- [`@java.lang.invoke.DontInline`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/0e4fc29a5ce4/src/share/classes/java/lang/invoke/DontInline.java#l30)
- [`@java.lang.invoke.Stable`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/0e4fc29a5ce4/src/share/classes/java/lang/invoke/Stable.java#l30)
- [`@sun.misc.Contended`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/0e4fc29a5ce4/src/share/classes/sun/misc/Contended.java#l33)

**Note:** All these mechanisms are non-standard. They apply only to OpenJDK and Oracle JDK. There is no standard way to hint JVM compiler, because there are many JVM implementations with completely different compilation strategies. Particularly, there are JVMs with no JIT compilation at all.

Comment: Really cool answer, thanks for information.
I'd like to add, that link you provided is pointing to source code, without descriptions of options, but in documentation of java command optiosn are covered more fully  ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html )
I'll edit answer, if you don't mind, to be more complete.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the *are* hints to the JVM’s optimizer that this method is a good candidate for inlining:

- It’s `static` or `private`, i.e. non-overridable
- It’s extremely short
- It’s called several times within a loop

In fact, your assumption that this method is a good candidate is based on the same technical evidence, so adding a hint that *you* think that this is a good inlining candidate would not add any new information, only redundancy.

So if the JVM still doesn’t inline the method, for whatever reason, despite all these technical properties speaking for inlining, there is no reason to assume that a non-mandatory, non-technical hint, most likely stemming from the same technical properties will turn the JVM’s decision.

You can pick any potential reason you want, protection against certain problems, too restrictive limits, even a flawed JVM implementation, in either case, you’ll see that the same reason applies to a method having your hint as well, even if it turns out to be an unfounded reason, as that also applies to a method without your hint. So in the latter case, the obvious solution would be to fix the flaws within the JVM, rather than adding a general hint mechanism.

A general hinting mechanism is especially questionable, as the code is supposed to be platform independent. If you look at a particular run in a known environment with a particular JVM implementation, things look different. E.g. HotSpot supports the `-XX:CompileCommand` option. So in your case, you could use 
`-XX:CompileCommand=inline,your/class/Name,multiplyByTwo` to try to convince the JVM to inline the method. Of course, the correct spelling is important. In your question, the method is once named `multipleByTwo`, then `multiplyByTwo`…

Comment: I know inlining rules (btw, i've heard many times that static/final modifiers don't play any role themselves, inlining used for all non-overriden methods, static/final just make override impossible). This example is trivial and truly can be solved without any hints, but there are many possible cases when JVM needs decent AI to figure out what's going on, and it's impossible to "fix it inside".

Comment: Well, that’s why these properties all are only *hints*. The JVM can inline overridable methods as well and so it can inline bigger methods or methods that are not called in a tight loop. As said, these props are all *hints* that this is a good candidate, so what’s your proposed personal hint adding to it? The known issue isn’t a complicated thing, it’s the maximum inline depth already mentioned in the comments. Since this is an implementation specific issue, there is no reason to introduce a general hinting feature instead of the implementation specific option.

Comment: I'm not talking about inlining itself. That's just the example when developer may know more than JVM does, probably not the best.

Comment: Well, if you’re not talking about inlining, it would be useful to specify, what you are actually talking about. Besides, Java is a platform independent language. You don’t know, on which actual hardware, which operating system, or which particular JVM implementation your code will run, but you think, you know *whatever-if-not-inlining-hints* better than the unknown JVM implementation, i.e. about how to execute your code? Well, I’m looking forward for a real example…